# How to display page onload popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using below code for onclick popup, but I need the same popup for onload - how can I solve this problem?

```
 <div class="app">
        <div class="canvas">

                <a href="#explode" class="ui--button" onclick="document.getElementById('boooom').setAttribute('src', 'assets/img/explode-med.gif');">Demo &mdash; Explode Modal</a>


        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="explode" class="ui--modal explode">
        <div>
            <a href="#close" class="material-icons ui--close">clear</a>
            <h4>Boooooom!!!</h4>
          <img src="assets/img/e2dshop.jpg"  >
            <!--<a href="#close" class="ui--button alt">close</a>-->
        </div>
        <div class="bg">
            <img src="assets/img/explode-med.gif" id="boooom">
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: This `onclick="document.getElementById('boooom').setAttribute('src', 'assets/img/explode-med.gif');` code open Your pop up thats correct ?

Comment: Please submit your script codes as well

Comment: i am not using any other scripts i have just used onclick function only.@sagar

Comment: yes its working fine.@htmlbrewery

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```
<script> 
 jQuery('window').on('load', function(){
   jQuery('#boooom').attr('src', 'assets/img/explode-med.gif');
 });
</script>
```

As well include jQuery lib.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ui--button").click();
});
```